# Resize a vector of atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, atomic, stdatomic

How to resize a vector of atomics ?

As an example, the following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::atomic<int>> v;
    v.resize(1000); // Problem here!
    v[0] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/vector:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::atomic<int>; _Args = {std::atomic<int>}]’:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::atomic<int>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::atomic<int>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::atomic<int>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::atomic<int>*]’
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::atomic<int>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::atomic<int>*; _Tp = std::atomic<int>]’
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:281:69:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = std::atomic<int>*; _ForwardIterator = std::atomic<int>*; _Allocator = std::allocator<std::atomic<int> >]’
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/vector.tcc:556:42:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = std::atomic<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::atomic<int> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_vector.h:667:41:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = std::atomic<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::atomic<int> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
main.cpp:8:17:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/atomic:601:7: error: declared here
       atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
       ^
```

Comment: Can you please include the compile error in your question

Comment: Error added : the problem is that atomics are non-copiable.

Comment: It does not look like you can resize a vector of `atomic`s - the best you can do is to size it upfront, say `std::vector<std::atomic<int>> v(1000)` and never resize it again. Of course this makes `std::vector` a de-facto array :-(

Comment: Consider using `std::array`

Comment: [Looks like](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cd4d07378f7e321) clang will work with all sequence containers as long you `emplace` into them. gcc only works with `std::array`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You can't...**

A [`std::atomic<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) is neither copy/move-constructible, nor can you assign one `std::atomic<T>` to another; this means that it doesn't have the requirements to use [`std::vector<...>::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)`(size_type)`.

> 23.3.6.2 **`vector` constructors, copy, and assignment** `[vector.const]`
>
> > ```
> > void resize (size_type sz);
> > ```
> >
> > *Requires*: `T` shall be CopyInsertable into `*this`.

<sup>**Note**: `std::vector::resize (size_type sz, T const& init)` isn't applicable either since that requires `T` to also be `MoveInsertable`.</sup>

---

**Proposed resolution**

You will need to use some other *container-type* which doesn't require already constructed data to be *moved*, *copied*, or *copy/move assigned*, upon modifying the elements already stored inside.

You could also define a wrapper around your `std::atomic` that fakes copy/moves/assigns, but actually just shallow read/writes the value of the underlying *atomic*.

Comment: Of course, invalidating iterators to `std::atomic` objects is a recipe for disaster if they're potentially being accessed by multiple threads at the time.  If not, you could consider C++20 `std::atomic_ref` to do atomic accesses to plain-`int` objects, and make sure you're careful to only resize the `vector<int>` when there aren't other threads accessing it.  That way they can safely read the `std::vector` object itself (the control block containing the start/end pointers), as well as dereference to access elements.

Answer (score 0):

`std::deque<std::atomic<int> >` can be resized. Note that `std::deque` can also provide `O(1)` random access just like `std::vector`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <atomic>

void print(std::deque<std::atomic<int> >& q) {
    for (auto& x : q) {
        std::cout << x.load() << ',';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::deque<std::atomic<int> > q;

    q.emplace_back(1);
    q.emplace_back(2);
    // 1,2
    print(q);

    q.resize(4);
    // 1,2,0,0
    print(q);

    q.resize(2);
    // 1,2
    print(q);

    //q.resize(5, 233);
    while (q.size() < 5) {
        q.emplace_back(233);
    }
    // 1,2,233,233,233,
    print(q);

    return 0;
}
```

`resize` with value does not work for `deque` because it requires copying the provided value, while `std::atomic` is not copyable. However, it can be achieved with repetitive `emplace_back`, which does not introduce much performance penalty because the expansion of `deque` does not require relocation of the existing data.

### References

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37870930/13688160

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating references to `std::atomic` objects is a recipe for disaster if they're potentially being accessed by multiple threads at the time.  If you need that, you can potentially use `std::dequeue< std::atomic<int> >` which allocates piecewise so it never moves an element after allocating.  (Note that growing a dequeue invalidates *iterators*, but not references to any individual element.)

But **the `std::dequeue` object itself** (and its internal linked list of chunks) **is still not atomic**, so you can't safely resize while other threads are doing things like `q[i].store(v, memory_order_release)`.  Only if you've just passed pointers to certain elements to other threads.  (Elements aren't contiguous so there's no guarantee that `&q[i+1] == &q[i]+1`, so you can't necessarily give other threads access to whole ranges.)

---

If you have a `std::vector` whose data is sometimes accessed by multiple threads, but other times the whole vector is owned exclusively by one thread for operations like resize, **this is a use-case for [C++20 `std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref)**.

Use `std::vector<int> v`.  When no other threads could accessing elements in it, or calling functions like `v.size()`, you can resize it as normal.

While no threads are calling functions that could change the control block at all, you can have any number of threads doing things like

```
   std::vector<int> v;
   // get some elements into v, start some threads
   static_assert(alignof(v[i]) >= std::atomic_ref<int>::required_alignment, "vector elements not guaranteed aligned enough for atomic_ref");

 // while no other threads could be calling v.push_back or any other non-const function except element access
   std::atomic_ref<int>  vi( v[i] );
   vi.store(2, std::memory_order_release);

   vi.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);  // and/or this

   auto tmp = vi.load(std::memory_order_acquire);  // and/or this
```

(The intended use-case for `atomic_ref` is to construct a new `atomic_ref` object every time you want to use it.  Don't keep one as a class member anyway, just a local variable.)

**Even a `.push_back` that doesn't reallocate would *not* be safe, though.**  That will change the members of the `std::vector<int>` object itself, which aren't atomic.  (And there's no way to make them atomic).   So this would be data race UB because other threads are accessing the `v` object, not just using an `int *` they already got from `v.data()`.

---

#### How this would break (or not) if you used it wrong

In practice (but *not* guaranteed by the standard) it's likely safe for one thread to be doing `.push_back()` as long as you're below the current capacity, as long as other threads are only indexing into it.  A typical implementation will keep a pointer to `.data()`, a pointer to the end of the reservation, and a pointer to the end of the in-use area, so `.size()` is `return end()-data()`.  `.push_back()` will only modify the end pointer, but `operator[]` will only read the `.data()` pointer.

If the library header works that way, then you don't even have data race UB in the actual C++ code seen by the compiler itself.  ISO C++ doesn't guarantee the internals, but this is a common implementation.

A debug built might also do bounds checking and read the `.end()` pointer in `operator[]` like `at()` does; then you'd have an actual data race.  In practice that's also unlikely to be fatal; most implementations for most machines don't have tearing within a naturally-aligned pointer-width object, so readers are going to see either an old or new value.  But this is definitely not guaranteed to be portable, and race-detectors will potentially notice.

But as long as you don't expect other threads to actually be accessing newly-pushed vector elements that have appeared since synchronizing with the pushing thread, it will happen to work on typical machines.

**I would not recommend this nasty hack of actually pushing while other threads are writing**.  I describe the details of what would happen just for educational purposes, *not* as justification for doing so.  If you do this anyway and it breaks, you get to keep both pieces.

Obviously actually reallocating could lead to crashes, if a thread got a reference to `v[i]` and then that reference was invalidated before use.  And/or stale data or missed updates from one thread modifying an element after it had already been copied.

---

Feel free to roll your own container with a size or end member used by one thread, with other threads only using the begin / data member.  With no conditional reallocate, it would even Just Work for `std::atomic<int>`, or if you want reallocation while one thread has exclusive ownership, still use `atomic_ref<T>` as above.  Or you could design the `push` function to take a `T`, not an `atomic<T>`, or just have it work like emplace_back.

Comment: A note on the first paragraph: deque does not invalidate pointers but it does invalidate iterators.

Comment: @Homer512: Thanks, that's an important distinction; updated.